# Android - Where and how securely is fingerprint information stored in a device

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I have been reading quite a bit about fingerprint sensors and their growing presence in smart phones. I understand that at the basic level, there is a digital image that gets registered and it serves as a template for authentication. I understand that fingerprint related processing takes place in a Trusted Execution Environment. However, I would like to know where the "template" gets saved and in what format?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Trusted Execution Environment (TEE)

Google has made a noteworthy step in the right direction by moving all print data manipulation to the Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) and providing strict guidelines for fingerprint data storage that manufacturers must follow.

- All fingerprint data manipulation is performed within TEE
- All fingerprint data must be secured within sensor hardware or trusted memory so that images of your fingerprint are inaccessible
- Fingerprint data can be stored on the file system only in encrypted form,
  regardless of whether the file system itself is encrypted or not
- Removal of the user must result in removal of the user's existing fingerprint data
- Root access must not compromise fingerprint data

[image]

Data Source [infinum.co](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/android-fingerprint-security)

Comment: So that's basically Hardware-backed storage, right? Does that mean that even with root access a user won't be able to access the fingerprint data?

Comment: Yep, It is. Even with Root access, its useless. Only the creator know how to sniff the storage.

Comment: So basically, your fingerprints are secured by obfuscation and some pseudo-cryptographic magic supposed to make you believe it's not only obfuscation. AFAIC, that's anything but a “noteworthy step in the right direction”. Really seems too weak to secure anything reliably.

Comment: If I'm reading right, they've taken pains to hide and obfuscate the data but it's still decyptable. It's not one-way encrypted like a password. I assume that's the nature of the scan image because it's never an exact match.

Comment: @jiggy I guess everything is possible either its data hiding or data hacking. Though its kinda possible to extract/view data if you root your device and do some code changes on your custom ROM.